# Spring cron expression - how to get last execution time

Tags: scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

In Spring I can get the nextExecution time using:

```
final CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression);
final Date nextExecutionDate = generator.next(new Date());
```

But how to get the last execution time from the cron expression ?

Comment: Hi @AliR have you find any way to get last execution time ??

Comment: Hi @SajithVijesekara, the scenario I was working on required that we need to know the last execution time even if the application gets restarted. We ended up adding a table in an already used Database, that gets updated on each time the cron expression gets triggered.

Answer (score 1):

It uses binary search to find the last execution time.

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression;

public class CronTest {

    @Test
    void cronTest() {
        CronExpression expression = CronExpression.parse("1 0/10 * * * ?");
        ZonedDateTime nextTime = expression.next(ZonedDateTime.now());
        assertNotNull(nextTime);
        ZonedDateTime prevTime = getPrevTime(expression, nextTime, nextTime.minusDays(1));
        assertEquals(nextTime.minusMinutes(10), prevTime);
    }

    private ZonedDateTime getPrevTime(CronExpression expression, ZonedDateTime nextTime, ZonedDateTime mayPrevTime) {
        ZonedDateTime start = mayPrevTime;
        ZonedDateTime end = nextTime;
        while (start.isBefore(end)) {
            ZonedDateTime middle = end.minusSeconds(
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() / 2));
            ZonedDateTime tmpNextTime = expression.next(middle);
            if (Objects.equals(tmpNextTime, nextTime)) {
                end = middle.minusSeconds(1);
            } else {
                start = middle.plusSeconds(1);
            }
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the additon/subtraction unit to 10 milliseconds instead of seconds. With seconds I got sometimes a difference in the minute, e.g. 29 instead of 30, it stopped at 29 minutes and 59 seconds: ```middle.minus(10, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```java
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator;
        final Date now = new Date();
        // 获取上一次执行时间
        CronSequenceGenerator cronSequenceGenerator = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 0/5 * * * ? ");
        // 获取下一次执行时间
        final Date next = cronSequenceGenerator.next(now);
        // 差值
        final long diff = next.getTime() - now.getTime();
        final Date last = new Date(now.getTime() - diff);
```